# The derivative of a function with respect to a matrix (or vector) doesn't have the same size as the original input.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I have the scenario where I am given historical data for m assets with $S^{(T+1)\times{m}}$ as the matrix for asset values over time. I want to find the derivative of this function $f$ with respect to the vector $w$. 
$$f(w)=\frac{1}{2} ln(a)+\frac{1}{2}$$
where
$$a=\frac{1}{T}\left\| b_1-cb_0\right\|^{2},$$
$$b_1=BS_{1:T}w,$$
$$b_0=BS_{0:T-1}w,$$
$$B=\textbf{I}-\frac{\textbf{11}^T}{T},$$
$$c=\frac{b_{0}^{T}b_1}{\left\|b_0 \right\|^{2}}$$
These equations come from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2019.108651), btw.

I've tried, like this:
\begin{aligned}\frac{df}{dw}
&=\frac{1}{2a} \times \frac{d}{dw}a \\
&=\frac{1}{2a} \times \frac{d}{dw} \left (\frac{1}{T}\left\| b_1-cb_0\right\|^{2} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2Ta} \times \frac{d}{dw} \left (\left\| b_1-cb_0\right\|^{2} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{Ta} \left(\frac{d}{dw}\left (b_1-cb_0  \right )\right)^T \left (b_1-cb_0  \right ) \\
\end{aligned}

The result of this derivation should be a matrix of the same size with $w$, which is m x 1, right?

The latter part $\left(b_1-cb_0  \right)$ is matrix of size T x 1. So, $\frac{d}{dw}\left (b_1-cb_0  \right)$ should be a matrix of size T x m.

I tried to calculate $\frac{d}{dw}\left (b_1-cb_0  \right )$ like this:
\begin{aligned} \frac{d}{dw}\left (b_1-cb_0  \right )
&=\frac{d}{dw}b_1 - \frac{d}{dw} cb_0 \\
&=\frac{d}{dw}b_1 - \left(\frac{d}{dw}c\right)b_0 - c \frac{d}{dw} b_0 \\
&= BS_{1:T}- \left(\frac{d}{dw}c\right)b_0 - cBS_{0:T-1} \\
\end{aligned}

$BS_{1:T}$ and $cBS_{0:T-1}$ would give matrices of size T x m. But I can't tell what size of $\left(\frac{d}{dw}c\right)$ since $b_0$ is a matrix of size T x 1. Can anyone kindly tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{c}\def\t{\tau}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
B_0 &= BS_{0}, \quad b_0 = B_0w, \quad db_0 = B_0\,dw \\
B_1 &= BS_{1}, \quad b_1 = B_1w, \quad db_1 = B_1\,dw \\
x &= \LR{\g b_0-b_1} = \LR{\g B_0-B_1}w \\
\a &= \|x\|^2_F = Ta \\
g &= \fracLR{{B_1^Tb_0}+{B_0^Tb_1}-2\g\,B_0^Tb_0}{b_0^Tb_0} \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product, which is a nice notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a
product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to calculate the desired gradient.

First, calculate
the differential of $\g$
$$\eqalign{
\g &= \frac{b_0:b_1}{b_0:b_0} \\
d\g
 &= \fracLR{\LR{b_0:db_1}+\LR{b_1:db_0}}{b_0:b_0}
  - \fracLR{\LR{b_0:b_1}\LR{2\,{b_0:db_0}}}{(b_0:b_0)^2} \\
 &= \frac{\LR{b_0:db_1}+\LR{b_1:db_0}-2\g\,b_0:db_0}{b_0:b_0} \\
 &= \frac{\LR{b_0:B_1dw}+\LR{b_1:B_0dw}-2\g\,b_0:B_0dw}{b_0:b_0} \\
 &= \fracLR{{B_1^Tb_0}+{B_0^Tb_1}-2\g\,B_0^Tb_0}{b_0^Tb_0}:dw \\
 &= g^Tdw \\
}$$
then the differential of $\a$
$$\eqalign{
\a &= {x:x} \\
d\a &= {2x:dx} \\
 &= 2x:\BR{b_0\,\c{dc} +\g B_0\,dw -B_1\,dw} \\
 &= 2x:\LR{B_0w\c{g^T} +\g B_0 -B_1}\c{dw} \\
 &= 2\BR{B_0wg^T +\g B_0 -B_1}^T\c{x}:dw \\
 &= 2\BR{B_0wg^T +\g B_0 -B_1}^T\c{\LR{\g B_0-B_1}w}:dw \\
}$$
and finally
the differential and gradient of $f$
$$\eqalign{
f &= \frac 12\LR{\log\LR{\frac{\a}{T}}+\o} \\
  &= \frac 12\BR{\log(\a)+\o-\log(T)} \\
df &= \frac 12\LR{\frac{d\a}{\a}} \\
  &= \fracLR{\LR{B_0wg^T+\g B_0-B_1}^T\LR{\g B_0-B_1}w}{\a}:dw \\
  &= \fracLR{\LR{S_0wg^T+\g S_0-S_1}^TB^TB\LR{\g S_0-S_1}w}{\a}:dw \\
\grad{f}{w}
 &= \frac{\LR{S_0wg^T+\g S_0-S_1}^TB\LR{\g S_0-S_1}w}{a/T} \\
}$$
where the last two lines take advantage of the fact
that $\;B^2=B=B^T$

Comment: Hi @greg. Thanks a lot! But is it possible to do this without using traces? I'm just wondering since I haven't really understood using trace, sorry.

Comment: @Haha The trace is not necessary, just replace each colon symbol with a transpose, e.g. $\;{x:My \implies x^TMy}\;$

Comment: ok thanks! and one more thing. I know $B=B^T$, but I don't think $B^2=B$ because B is not an identity matrix. Am I right?

Comment: Why can we say, for example, that $dc=g^T dw$ equals $\frac{dc}{dw}=g$?

Comment: @Haha The way you've defined $B\,$ it is equal to the [Centering Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix) and is therefore idempotent. As for the vector $g,\,$ it is the gradient of $c$ so those two relationships are equivalent by definition.

Comment: I still don't understand the latter part. If those two equations are equivalent by definition, what definition that you refer to? Do you have any reference for me to read about it? Thanks @greg

Comment: @Haha The definition of the gradient.  If $g$ is the gradient of $c$ then $\,g=\frac{dc}{dw}\,$ and for any change in the independent variable $w$ (which I will call $dw$) the Taylor expansion for the change in the function value is given by $\,dc=g^Tdw\;$